# Custom Domain in Logstash S3 Output Plugin

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, logstash, elastic-stack

I'm running into a wall trying to figure out how to get rid of ".amazonaws.com" from the URL that is built from the Logstash S3 output plugin. It does not work in the environment I am in.
I have tried many things such as using the endpoint option and specifying
https://s3.region.customDomain but the AWS SDK is still trying to use .amazonaws.com. Is there any way to get around this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify your endpoint using 'endpoint' and then add 'force_path_style => true' to force plugin to use the provided endpoint as-is.

See example below:

```
output {
   s3{
     endpoint => "http://minio-s3:9000"
     bucket => "documents"
     prefix => "events/%{+YYYY-MM}"
     ...
     additional_settings => {
         force_path_style => true
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it